# Two primary key reference to a foreign key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

In our database system, we have student and personnel fields. They have PersonnelCardId and StudentCardId and we made them primary key. Then we have a payment device which holds cardID and we declared that it is a foreign key. And we couldn't insert a row in that case and after a research we learned that we can't reference two primary key to a foreign key. So how can we fix this situation? Thanks.

Comment: any table which is a 'child' (e.g. has a foreign key pointing at another 'parent' table) **MUST** have a matching record in the parent table before you can insert into the child. e.g. create your personnel and/or student records BEFORE you isnert into the payment table.

Comment: Okey, our problem is that we have two different Card id, one is studentCardId and the other is personnelCardId in two different table named Students and Personnels and we declared them primary keys. So according the your definition, if we can add a matching record for one table, it will fail for another table. So how can we fix this problem? What should we change?

Answer (score 5):

As you've stated, a foreign key can't reference two different tables at the same time.  With your current schema, the `cardID` foreign key can only reference either `PersonnelCardId` or `StudentCardId`...

If I understand correctly, your schema looks something like:

```
PersonnelCard
----------------
PersonnelCardID - PK
PersonnelCardFields


StudentCard
----------------
StudentCardID - PK
StudentCardFields


PaymentDevice
----------------
PaymentDeviceID - PK
CardID - FK
```

To resolve this, you'll have to find a way to combine the `PersonnelCard` and `StudentCard` tables...

```
Card
----------------
CardID - PK
CardType - (Personnel or Student)
CardFields
```

The FK on the `PaymentDevice` table can now reference the PK in the new `Card` table.

Comment: Actually, we don't want to combine personnel and students tables but we come up with another solution which is that we put studentCardId and personnelCardId into PaymentDevice field as a column and we want to constraint them like that, alter table PaymentDevice add constraint PaymentDevice_con check((StudentCardID=NOT NULL AND PersonnelCardId=NULL) OR vice versa) ; however it seems not working so what do you think? Isn't it logical?

Comment: @user1463542 When comparing to `NULL`, you'll want to use `IS` instead of `=`... `(StudentCardID IS NOT NULL AND PersonnelCardId IS NULL)`

Comment: @user1463542 Instead of combining the `student` and `personnel` tables, could you still create a new `card` table, and have `personnel ` and `student` have their own FKs to this `card` table?